# Getting OneSignal UserID with Unity (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onesignal

In my app, I have some push notification subscribers (OneSignal). I am trying to get the user id's like this:

```
OneSignal.GetIdsAvailable(IdsAvailable);
....
....
private void IdsAvailable(string userID, string pushToken)
{
    playeridx = userID;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UserID:" + userID);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("pushToken:" + pushToken);
}
```

But I get an error: "OneSignal does not contain a definition for GetIdsAvailable."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using a method found in the [OneSignal Windows SDK](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/windows-phone-sdk#section--getidsavailable-). If you want to do this in Unity, setup the Unity SDK (if you haven't done so already) and then perhaps use [GetPermissionSubscriptionState](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/unity-sdk#section--getpermissionsubscriptionstate-) to retrieve the `userId` and `pushToken` of the current user, instead of using `.GetIdsAvailable()`.

Answer (score 0):

As I am seeing, we must use the code bellow to get the UserID. But, which event is triggered when the UserID arrives from Onesignal? if I use the UserID right after this line, it always has the UserID? It sounds strange for me, because, sometimes it could not had received the UserID yet.

```
OSPermissionSubscriptionState state = OneSignal.GetPermissionSubscriptionState();
extraMessage += " UserId: "+state.subscriptionStatus.userId;
```