# How do I retrieve all player_id of devices connected in OneSignal?

Tags: push-notification, unity-game-engine, onesignal

I am trying to do a test on OneSignal in Unity. I want to send push notification to a specific user listed in OneSignal via code.

I have found that connected devices have player ids and I want to grab all those player_ids for checking purposes. How can it be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting OneSignal UserID with Unity (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957612/getting-onesignal-userid-with-unity-c)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. what i want to do is first grab all the ids but not the current userID.